# Fish Wrap all commands in a function

Tags: fish

I have a function that is setup to send status updates to anybar.

```
function e --description 'Run command' \
           --argument-names command
  anybar yellow; eval $command; anybar green;
end
```

I am trying to find a way wrap all of my commands that I give through cli to fish in this function.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of this method, try adding the following to your `config.fish`:

```
function my_preexec --on-event fish_preexec
    anybar yellow
end

function my_postexec --on-event fish_postexec
    anybar green
end
```

This will run these functions before and after every command, without requiring the potentially-explosive `eval`.